# Is there anything I can do to make up for missing fasting?

Tags: sawm, ramadan

I live in the UK and this year the times for fasting Ramadan are too long for me to do. I am unable to fast the prescribed times as I will not be able to carry out my duties at work, I am also on my probation period so if I make any mistakes I'm in trouble.

Is there anything I can do that can make up for my lack of fasting this year?

Answer (score 2):

According to Quran if you have skipped fasting in the month of ramadan, because of some reason then you should make up those fasts by fasting on other days i.e, in months other than ramadan. When you can with the intention of fulfilling the fasts of ramadan. This can be done any-time in a year.

Source - Quran Al-Baqarah, 2:184

[image]
 [Fasting for] a limited number of days. So whoever among you is ill or on a journey [during them] - then an equal number of days [are to be made up]. And upon those who are able [to fast, but with hardship] - a ransom [as substitute] of feeding a poor person [each day]. And whoever volunteers excess - it is better for him. But to fast is best for you, if you only knew.

Comment: You should have a very strong, acceptable reason for not fasting Ramadan in-time.

Comment: why do you put a -1, without reason

Comment: Because the answer doesn't answer the question. The question has a specific case which requires specific answer, not a general answer that doesn't have any references or proofs.

Comment: check the edit, I posted in answer, from Quran                       "....And upon those who are able [to fast, but with hardship] - a ransom [as substitute] of feeding a poor person [each day]. **And whoever volunteers excess - it is better for him**."

Comment: This still doesn't answer the question. The question is: "is heavy work a good reason for skipping fasting in Ramadan and doing it later?" which AFAIK is not. Your answer is so general that it even might make him think what he did is OK.

Comment: I guess you can't seem to work it out from the Quranic verse I gave as proof And upon those who are able [to fast, **but with hardship***] - a ransom [as substitute] of feeding a poor person [each day]. And whoever volunteers excess - it is better for him."   *=with hardship means what the questioner is asking

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19445/discussion-between-tamer-shlash-and-yawar).

Comment: **<Comments deleted>** Take it to the chatroom linked above.

Answer (score 1):

The fast will still be obligatory for you, those exempted from the obligatory fasts are immature, insane, sick (so sick that fasting could further harm), travele(according to Shariah), old.

You should keep the fasts and insha Allah will make it easier for you. However if you break any of the fasts you will have to make Qadha of the missed fasts after Ramadhan.

Answer (score -3):

if the fast realy bothers you that you cannot work properly than you should feed a poor for each day you didnt fast or you can complete your fast later not in the ramadan